# Am getting this error in jhipster : error.internalServerError

Tags: jhipster

While inserting data's into the **jhipster** generated code, am getting

```
 error.internalServerError
```

the Above error and also in my Console am getting this

```
Table 'kaisifydemo.job_post' doesn't exist
```

error. But I created the Entity Job Post and gave the relationship also. So what was the problem?

can someone clarify me? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you getting liquibase errors when you first start your application?

Comment: Nope abhi, when open my application in some particular url i got :( error.internalServerError) that error only, After that there are many errors are occurs in my console also that was liquibase errors.

Answer (score 3):

Yo guys, finally i found the answer for my own question. The reason for my error was improper relationship between two entities. Give relationship names properly. Thank you